# Algorithm to draw maximum triangles in a planar graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, max

I have a random number of vertices distributed randomly on a plane.

I need an algorithm to tell me how to draw a graph as following :
The graph must have the maximum number of triangle faces.
Edges must not cross each others (planar graph).

I need to know what is the name of the graph I want to draw, Then I need to know if there is a good algorithm or library to help me draw that.

---

Printing a result to the stdout like the following is more than enough :

> (v=vertex; e=edge; k=total number of faces)
>
> e0 : v0 v1
>
> e1 : v0 v2
>
> e2 : v0 v3
>
> e3 : v1 v2
>
> e4 : v1 v3
>
> K : 4

This should be the output of a simple graph like this:

[image: graph]

But the algorithm should support graphs with much larger number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

You want a triangulation, and any such will do: they all have the same number of faces.

One approach is this:

- Find the convex hull of the vertices. Say `v[1]...v[n]` going clockwise round the convex hull. Triangulate this convex hull as `v[1]v[2]v[3]`, `v[1]v[3]v[4]`, `v[1]v[4]v[5]`... etc. (ie: draw rays from `v[1]` to each vertex to subdivide it into triangles).
- Now update your triangulation by adding one vertex at a time:

  - If the new vertex is inside an existing triangle, subdivide the existing triangle into 3 parts by drawing rays from each corner to the new vertex.
  - If the new vertex lies on an existing edge, cut the two existing triangles (one on either side of the edge) into half by drawing rays from the vertices opposite the edge to the new vertex. If the new vertex is on the edge of the convex hull, you'll only have one triangle rather than two to cut in half.

If you're looking for a "nice" triangulation, consider the [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). This has the property that it maximizes the minimum angle in the triangulation which will tend to produce nicer-looking images as simpler approaches such as above will often give you very thin triangles.